# Elasticsearch: no JDK found... but JAVA_HOME seems set properly

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, elasticsearch, jvm

When I'm trying to install elasticsearch (Ubuntu 16.04) I get the error message:

```
elasticsearch[15885]:  * no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME
```

But I have only one Java and I think JAVA_HOME is set properly...

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means when elasticsearch is starting up it cannot find the JAVA_HOME variable. You need to make sure JAVA_HOME is globally set. If there is a init.d or elasticsearch startup file put it there. Also you can add it in `/etc/default/elastic` or create a profile for elasticsearch in `/etc/profile.d/elasticsearch`.

So to recap, first debug and understand where the problem lies: 1) check how elasticsearch is starting up;  2) check the init/start up file and 3) Then put the JAVA_HOME in the appropriate place.

Comment: That's the point!  Thank you very much!

Problem was I'm need to use an old elasticsearch version (0.9) and my java 8 was not in the profile.d script.

The solution was add "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64" to JDK_DIRS variable in /etc/profile.d/elasticsearch.